# does EVERY media query provoke a http request?

Tags: css, http, media-queries, httprequest

I would like to know, if there is a difference in HTTPS requests in these two examples:

1.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 40em) {
  .example {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

2.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 40em) {
    .example {
        width: 100vw;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 40em) {
.example {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

The difference is that in 1 there is just one media query (just one request?) and in the second two (two requests?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you are using media as different files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="mediatype and|not|only (media feature)" href="mystylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any HTTP requests at all. It is just checking device parameters and applying necessary CSS rules. I think in general it there is no impact on performance, only bigger file size.